# expect adding curly brackets to password containing special characters

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I wanted to write up a small expect script and another bash script to save the effort of typing password in ssh connection.

Here goes the scripts:

```
// ssh.exp, the real workhorse
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# usage: ./ssh.exp host user pass

set host [lrange $argv 0 0]
set user [lrange $argv 1 1]
set pass [lrange $argv 2 2]

spawn ssh $user@$host
match_max 100000
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$pass\r"
send -- "\r"
interact

// the bash script to call it
#!/bin/bash

host='my.host.com'
user='someuser'
pass='Qwerty389$'

./ssh.exp $host $user $pass
```

However, when the test scripts run, the ssh server always complains that the password is incorrect.

I tried escaping the dollar sign, like `pass='Qwerty389\$'`, but to no avail.

Put the debug statement `exp_internal 1` into the expect script, and it shows that the password sent is:

```
send: sending "{Qwerty389$}\r" to { exp6 }  // without escaping $
send: sending "{Qwerty389\$}\r" to { exp6 } // escaping $ in password
```

Not sure why expect put the curly brackets around the password passed to it. I verified that if there is no dollar sign in the password, there would not be the brackets.

Any help?

Comment: Obligatory suggestion to use public-key authentication instead of password authentication, bypassing the need to use `expect` at all.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the suggestion. But the scenario here is the host name is a virtual one, the real ssh host keeps changing each time I log in, like `somehost02`, `somehost07`, etc. And it looks like the server side doesn't check the ssh key at all, only prompting for password.

Comment: You are just passing the host name as an argument, which you can do with an ordinary script. You can look at the output of `ssh -v` to see if it is attempting to PKA.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion, @chepner. Just checked with `ssh -v`, and you are right, the server does try to PKA first. I was wrong about this. But the problem is I don't know what specific server I would be on before the connection is established. So it probably is hard for me to put the key file onto the server. I mean, I may have to put one copy of the certificate onto every server in the cluster.

Comment: As long as you know the complete set of servers you *might* be connected to, you can copy the public key to as many servers as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell code needs to quote variables:

```
./ssh.exp "$host" "$user" "$pass"
```

The expect code should not treat lists like plain strings. Extract the arguments with

```
lassign $argv host user pass
```

or if your expect is too old to have `lassign`, do

```
foreach {host user pass} $argv break
```

or (less DRY)

```
set host [lindex $argv 0]
set user [lindex $argv 1]
set pass [lindex $argv 2]
```

Comment: This works! Thank you, Glenn. The testing shows the quotes around `$host`, `$user`, and  `$pass` are not necessary in the calling bash script, but the `lassign` makes the real difference. Of all the examples I could find online about the expect script, it looks everyone is using `set` to retrieve the arguments. Could I ask why `lassign` would not add the redundant curly brackets around the password containing special chars?

Comment: When you use `set pass [lrange $argv 2 2]`, you get a **list** containing one element. When Tcl stringifies a list, it may put braces around elements containing non-word characters. The problem is you create `pass` as a list, then later you use it as a string. The solution is to create it as a string in the first place. `lrange` is the wrong way to extract single elements out of a list because that command returns a list. You might have seen examples using `lindex` -- `set first [lindex $argv 0]; set second [lindex $argv 1]; ...` That style is fine, but `lassign` is more concise.

Comment: As an example, try this in a `tclsh` session: `set argv [list first second "third$"]; set pass [lrange $argv 2 2]; puts "$pass"; puts "[lindex $pass 0]"` -- this demonstrates the way Tcl uses braces to protect list elements with non-word characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your enlightment, Glenn! Now I know both "how" and "why".     :-)

Comment: The shell code DOES need to quote the variables properly, like `./ssh.exp "$host" "$user" "$pass"`. Initially, I thought they were unnecessary. But I was wrong. Without the quotes, sometimes the ssh connection was successful, but it could hang at times as well. Even when the ssh connection was successful, there were occasions that the first two lines couldn't be displayed in `vi`. Also, searching a string in `vi` put the cursor in the weird positions, not on the first character of the found string. All these problems go away when the variables are properly quoted in the calling bash script.